# Error npm test using mocha installtion. I'm using VS code

Tags: mocha.js

```
npm test
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\dell\Documents\Gan-crypt\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\dell\Documents\Gan-crypt\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.    
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-06T05_30_21_377Z-debug.log
```

Comment: looks like you are running the command in wrong directory, just verify if package.json is present in the directory where you are running command from

Comment: I know now the source of my problem. Thank you! I'm practicing to programming truffle and ganache-cli using npm commands.

Comment: Hi, i just wanted to point out that you need to improve the formatting here. Do remember to always check the preview of your posts before posting. In this case, you need to remove the unnecessary blockquotes and strong texts. You can also add blockquotes for the error messages, also see this [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more tips and guidance. Have a great day! :D